# How to "reload" JavaScript / CSS when user navigates pages in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm writing my first portfolio website./ I just finished the main page, and now I'm adding more pages. Additionally, the navigation bar component uses JavaScript to control some of its functionality.

When I use the navigation bar to switch to a different page, the script I use does not reset. For example, in the mobile view, you could use the navigation bar (which turns into a sidebar when the burger is clicked) to go to the *projects* page. After navigating there, *the JavaScript file no longer applies*. Thus, the `document.querySelector('body').style.overflowY = 'hidden';` line doesn't apply after the user changes page, among other things.

Simplified problem:

The main issue is that the JavaScript is not refreshing. For testing, I put `console.log("refresh");` in that JavaScript file, and as I use the links to navigate through the site, that statement only prints once. How do I configure Next to print that upon each page load?

Navbar:

```
import Link from 'next/Link';
import NavbarStyles from "../styles/navbarStyles";
const Navbar = () => (
    <nav>
        <div className="logo">
            <h4><Link href="/"><a>Red Williams</a></Link></h4>
        </div>
        <ul className="nav-links">
            <li><Link href="/resume"><a>Resume</a></Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/projects"><a>Projects</a></Link></li>
            <li><Link href="/contact"><a>Contact</a></Link></li>
        </ul>
        <div className="burger">
            <div className="line-1"></div>
            <div className="line-2"></div>
            <div className="line-3"></div>
        </div>

        {/* Styles */}
        <style jsx global>{NavbarStyles}</style>

        {/* Sidebar */}
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/slide.js"></script>
    </nav>  
);

export default Navbar;
```

JavaScript file (slides navbar on burger click):

```
const slide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');
    const navLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-links li');
## 
    console.log("refresh");

    burger.addEventListener('click', ()=> {

        // Toggle sidebar
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');

        // Time link animation
        navLinks.forEach((link, index) => {
            if (link.style.animation) {
                link.style.animation = '';
            } else {
            link.style.animation = `navLinkFade 0.5s ease forwards ${index / 7 + 0.25}s`;
            }
        });

        // Change burger/X
        burger.classList.toggle('toggle');

        // Toggle scrolling
        if (document.querySelector('body').style.overflowY === '') {
            document.querySelector('body').style.overflowY = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.querySelector('body').style.overflowY = '';
        }
    });
}
slide();
```

At first, I thought it was an issue with the event listener on the burger, but the `console.log("refresh");` line doesn't run when the page changes, so that cannot be the case.

I know the issue, I just don't know how to solve it. This is my first Next/React project. Also, if you have suggestions on "best practices" when it comes to this code, especially the JavaScript side of it, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't understand how React works.
You are not supposed to include javascript as you did

`<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/scripts/slide.js"></script>`

but with `import MyComponent from './path/to/component`

On top of that, it's very bad to manipulate the DOM directly, you should instead use hooks from React.

A very basic example of what you are trying to do [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-fire-rr9bp?file=/pages/index.js).

I suggest you read the React doc and try to understand it's concepts first.